# How to convert interger numbers into brazilain price format

Tags: gawk

i have integer numbers like below on left side in a file for products and need to convert them into brazilaian format like on right side.

- 100 =>100,00
- 84  => 84,00
- 1011 => 1.011,00

Comment: In which of the numerous languages that you've specified would you like to do this? It looks like the two answers have assumed PHP - is that correct?

Comment: Actually i want in gawk , but i mention other languages as if someone writes a function and use that in whichever i want.

Answer (score 1):

Use `number_format()` -

```
echo number_format(100, 2, ',', '.');
echo number_format(84, 2, ',', '.');
echo number_format(1011, 2, ',', '.');
```

**Output** -

```
100,00
84,00
1.011,00
```

[Docs](http://php.net/Number_format)